# Cannot find module in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, crud

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './models/todo'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Basel\Desktop\Todo List\routes\api.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)

C:\Users\Basel\Desktop\Todo List>
```

Why this application won't start up? I've already tried a global npm install.

Comment: Where is the `models` folder?

Comment: You need to provide more details.  Do you have a `todo.js` file in the `models` directory that's at the same level as the file that's calling `require`?

Comment: Yes. Originally I called it to todo. I refactored it and changed the title to todos.js. Subsequently I changed the path in my routes so that it would reflect the change (to ./models/todos') but that didn't work either.

Comment: The models folder is under another folder called app. Lemme gues I got the paths wrong?

Comment: So is it in the location `\Todo List\app\models\todo.js`?

Comment: Yes it is in this location.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In `./models/todo`, the period indicates that node will look in the *same* folder that `api.js` is in, which would look for `\Todo List\routes\models\todo.js`. This does not start from the root of the application. To require this, you'll need to us two periods to jump up a level, and specify the app path as well:

```
var todo = require('../app/models/todo');
```

Comment: in my case node parses ../ as it is in var todo = require('../app/models/todo');  so output would be ../app/models/todo not parent/app/models/todo!

Answer (score 14):

maybe you did not set the system value : NODE_PATH; it should point to your global module location;

in Linux: `export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` works good for me;

Answer (score -1):

in my case, the file name i had given in my require statement was wrong. I had my models file named posts.js and i was using require('./models/post'). It worked after i changed it to require ('.models/posts')