# cannot find module.js error 471 win 10

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, postgresql

strong textC:\Users\eurnet>git clone C:\Users\eurnet\node-postgres-todo
fatal: destination path 'node-postgres-todo' already exists and is not an empty directory.

C:\Users\eurnet>node server/models/database.js

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\eurnet\server\models\database.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

what should do ??\

Comment: seems, you already have that folder, try deleting it. or give a new name to cloned one,
`git clone C:\Users\eurnet\node-postgres-todo node-postgres-todo-1`

Comment: press ls -l, in `C:\Users\eurnet>` and pls paste the result

Comment: C:\Users\eurnet>git clone C:\Users\eurnet\node-postgres-todo-1
fatal: destination path 'node-postgres-todo-1' already exists and is not an empty directory.

C:\Users\eurnet>node server/models/database.js
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\eurnet\server\models\database.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

Comment: you have taken a wrong command, please check my command again, now try with 2, `git clone C:\Users\eurnet\node-postgres-todo node-postgres-todo-2`

Comment: i change to 2 ...the same .. and i test ls-l and i find some files

Comment: ls-l-depth-0 you mean this file??

Comment: [check this once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446514/cannot-find-module-in-nodejs)

Comment: where should i put ( var todo = require)... in database.js

Comment: you can place it at the top, with the correct path

Comment: i write in database.js  var todo = require('node-postgres-todo-2/server/models/database.js');   .... and still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command. Please note that the following command will delete the folder node-postgres-todo and clone the project provided you give the GIT repository path where specified. (Below command is considering you are using windows environment)

```
rmdir /s node-postgres-todo & git clone <GIT PATH>
```